# how can I transform this three column dataframe to a one column with the value of the column in the highest value in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

how can I transform this three column dataframe to a one column with the value of the column in the highest value in a row. For example, first row becomes -1, second row 1.

dataframe overview:-

[image]

Comment: use  df.max(axis=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`idxmax` is what you looking for

```
df["max"] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks al ot, it worked . you are a real life saver